# How can I batch-process (crop) these images?

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I would like to know how to (as fast as possible) mass edit (means everything at once - around 100 images): What I want to do is remove both (upper and downer one) big black lines as well as remove (so simply cut a bit more of an image) the taskbar at the down side.

Instead of the cut part, it should NOT be white color but just black color (+ taskbar below) removed.

How do I do that with around 100 images? Searching for the quickest way.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python with Python Imaging Library to crop images.

```
easy_install PIL
```

Then in your script:

```
import Image
```

For each image, crop away the edges--e.g.,

```
im = Image.open(filename)
region = im.crop( (100,100,500,600) )
region.save(newfilename)
```

Comment: Im not programmer. Don't know programming :-( Anything else please?

Comment: It graphic related. Not just programming.

Comment: IrfanView is the way to go if you don't like programming.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) for batch processing images. It has a lot of options for cropping.

File -> Batch Conversion -> Tick `Use advanced options` -> Advanced button